# Accessing a std::map of std::map like an array

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap

I have initialize a std::map of a std::map like as below:

```
static std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, float>> _ScalingMapFrequency = {
            {"mHz",    {{"mHz",     1.0}}},
            {"mHz",    {{"Hz",      1e-3}}},

            {"Hz",     {{"mHz",     1e+3}}},
            {"Hz",     {{"Hz",      1.0}}}};
```

And now I am trying to access the float values in the following way:

```
std::cout<<"  the scaling factor is     :"<<_ScalingMapFrequency["mHz"]["Hz"];
```

There is no problem when I compile and run the code but I am expecting to get "1e-3" instead I am always getting a "0". I need to access the std::map "_ScalingMapFrequency" as an array, that being the design decision.

What mistake I am making ? Please give me some pointer and I would greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A map cannot have duplicate keys, thus when you do `{"mHz",    {{"Hz",      1e-3}}},` for the second time, it overwrites the first one, as opposed to merge them.

You should change the constructor so that they are merged to begin with.

```
 {"mHz",    {{"mHz",     1.0}},
 {"mHz",    {{"Hz",      1e-3}},
```

Should become

```
 {"mHz",    {{"mHz",     1.0},
            {"Hz",      1e-3}}},
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I missed that basic thingy. What I need is to have the mapping of {"mHz",    {{"Hz",      1e-3}}} and {"mHz",    {{"mHz",      1e-3}}}... How could I achieve this without mentioning "mHz" for the second time...I mean how do I correctly initialize without repetition of the key ?

Comment: Ohh awesome...Let me try that. Thank you so very much for your quick reply !!

Comment: If the brackets are confusing, I suggest initializing it in 2 steps, first the inner map, and then use it to init the outer map

Comment: Thank you so much !! It worked like a charm...:) :) I dont know how could I missed that basic stuffs ...