# How to initialize std::map by an array?

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap

I have a task to fill empty `std::map<char, std::set<std::string>> myMap`, by an array

```
const char* s[] = { "car", "sun", "surprise", "asteriks", "alpha", "apple" };
```

and print it using `range based for` and `bindings`. Result, should be like `S: sun, surprise`

The last one(printing) I have already implement in this way

```
for (const auto& [k, v] : myMap)
{
    cout << "k = " << k << endl;
    std::set<std::string>::iterator it;
    for (it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << "var = " << *it << endl;
    }
}
```

**But how can I initilase this map, by `const char* s[]` in right way?**

P.S. I know, how to initialize it like std::map<char, `std::set<std::string>> myMap = { {'a', {"abba", "abart", "audi"} } };` and I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23214788/accessing-a-stdmap-of-stdmap-like-an-array) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54113566/how-to-initialize-a-structure-field-stdmapstdstring-stdstring-called-pa) posts on StackOverflow, but I am still have no idea, how to do this by this array.

Comment: a map contains keys and mapped values, it isnt obvious how the array should be filled to the map

Comment: OT: Why don't you use a range-for loop for printing the set as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
const char* s[] = { "car", "sun", "surprise", "asteriks", "alpha", "apple" };
std::map<char, std::set<std::string>> myMap;

for (auto str : s)
    myMap[str[0]].insert(str);

// Result: {
//     'a' -> {"alpha", "apple", "asteriks"},
//     'c' -> {"car"},
//     's' -> {"sun", "surprise"}
// }
```